# sort associate array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, sorting

```
function mysort($arr)
{
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    $j = $i;
    while ($j > 0 && $arr[$j] < $arr[$j-1]) {
        $tmp = $arr[$j-1];
        $arr[$j-1] = $arr[$j];
        $arr[$j] = $tmp;
        $j--;
    }
}

return $arr;
}

$array = array(
'a' => '1',
'f' => '3',
'g' => '5',
's' => '2',
'r' => '8'
 );
$values = array_values($array);

$sorted = array();
foreach (mysort($values) as $key=> $value) {
$sorted[$value] = $array[$value];
}

print_r($sorted);
```

i am completely lost here. what i'd like to do is sort the array $array according to the values so that the output is

a = 1

s = 2

f = 3

g = 5

r = 8

however i am trying to do this without using any sort methods such as asort, usort or ksort. just my own function.

Comment: I can't understand your question correctly. Can you please make it clear to me.Thank you.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use such methods? `asort($array);` seems far simpler.

Comment: the array that ive built in the code i want to sort it by the numbers descending while keeping the associations and to do this without using a method such as asort($array) which i admit makes it easier.

Comment: so we're talking homework here?

Comment: yes. indeed. i have managed to sort it alphabetically through keys instead of using ksort. but just couldnt figure out how to sort by values

Comment: There are many, MANY ways to sort arrays manually. Take a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Popular_sorting_algorithms in each section there is a link to the specific algorithm, with examples of pseudocode that you should easily be able to rewrite in PHP

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

Here I simple loop through all elements of `$array` and save them sorted in `$sorted`. In the first if statement I check if  either the `$sorted` array is empty OR the current element of `$array`  is bigger than the last element of the sorted array. If it is true I just append the element at the end to the `$sorted` array.

E.g. (pseudo code):

```
empty($sorted) || end($sorted) < current($array)
```

Otherwise I'll enter the else part where I loop through the `$sorted` array to find the spot where the current element of `$sorted` is less than the current element of `$array` AND the next element of `$sorted` is bigger than the current element of `$array` (So to say to find the spot where the current element of `$array` has to go in between).

E.g (pseudo code):

```
current($sorted) < current($array) && next(current($sorted)) > current($array)
```

And if this is the case I first cut off the part from the current element of the `$sorted` array and save it in a tmp variable. Then I append the current element from `$array` and then append the part which I cut off again at the end of the `$sorted` array.

```
<?php

    $array = [
            'a' => '1',
            'r' => '8',
            'g' => '5',
            'f' => '3',
            's' => '2',



    ];

    $sorted = [];
    $keys = array_keys($array);


    for($count = 0; $count < count($array); $count++) {

        $tmpKeys = array_keys($sorted);
        if(empty($sorted) || $sorted[$tmpKeys[count($sorted)-1]] < $array[$keys[$count]]) {
            $sorted[$keys[$count]] = $array[$keys[$count]];
        } else {

            for($innerCount = 0; $innerCount < count($sorted)-1; $innerCount++) {

                if($sorted[$tmpKeys[$innerCount]] < $array[$keys[$count]] && $array[$keys[$count]] < $sorted[$tmpKeys[$innerCount+1]]) {
                    $tmp = array_splice($sorted, $innerCount+1);
                    $sorted[$keys[$count]] = $array[$keys[$count]];
                    $sorted = array_merge($sorted, $tmp); 
                }

            }
        }

    }

    print_r($array);
    print_r($sorted);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [a] => 1 [r] => 8 [g] => 5 [f] => 3 [s] => 2 )
Array ( [a] => 1 [s] => 2 [f] => 3 [g] => 5 [r] => 8 )
```